# Input text apperas twice while entering a character

Tags: android, jquery, cordova-2.0.0

I have a Input text type search the problem is when a i run the app on emulator its working fine. But when i run the app on the device and enter a character in the Input field it shows two text box at that time I don't know why its happening .
Here is the code for Input Text:

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>CRM</h1>
        <div class="srchdiv" data-theme="b" , data-overlay-theme="b">
<input type="search" placeholder="Search" data-icon="search" id="searchfield">
<a href="#popupMenu" class="btn_continue" data-rel="popup" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="continuebtn" data-transition="slideup"></a>
    <a href="#popupMenu1" class="btn_delete" data-rel="popup" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="deletebtn" data-transition="pop" ></a>
</div>
</div>
```

and the CSS file i used is:

```
.srchdiv{
top:43px;
position:fixed;
width:100%;
margin:0;
padding:0;
background-color: #999999;}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please clarify if this is actually an application or a web page you're opening from your device?

Comment: its an phonegap application